# 12 AM is considered as next day

Tags: javascript, momentjs

`12 AM` is considered as next day

```
timeone = "5/18/2017 01:00 AM"
currenTime = "5/18/2017 05:55 AM"
timetwo = "5/18/2017  12:00 AM"
```

I see that this `condition` fails when the time is `12:00 AM`, how do i handle this
case?

```
timeone.isBefore(currentTime) => passes
currentTime.isBefore(timetwo) => fails

if (timeone.isBefore(currentTime) && currentTime.isBefore(timetwo)) {

}
```

**Update:**

```
var timeone = moment(time1, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
var timetwo = moment(time2, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
var currentTime = moment(currentTime, 'MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm a');
```

Comment: That time does not normally exist so Moment tries to fix it as documented. Are you trying to handle split seconds?

Comment: 12am is silly: http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/faqs/is-midnight-12-am-or-12-pm-faq-time

Comment: 12:00AM is better expressed as 00:00 -- it's the epoch of a new day. As such, `timeTwo` is before `currentTime`, so the library is correct.

Comment: @Shame Could you please edit the question and explain what output you want and why? I mean, if you feed Moment with e.g. "February 31" there're only two simple options: add 3 days to February 28 or crash.

Answer (score 8):

"12:00 AM" and "12:00 PM" are technically ambiguous, because AM means "before noon", and PM "after noon". Since noon is neither before nor after noon, and midnight could be considered the end of one day or the start of the next, neither label fits.

However, it's a very common interpretation that 12:00AM means midnight (00:00 in 24-hour notation) and 12:00PM means noon (12:00 in 24-hour notation). [Wikipedia has a section on various interpretations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/12-hour_clock#Confusion_at_noon_and_midnight).

This is the interpretation your library is using, so "5/18/2017  12:00 AM" = "5/18/2017  00:00", which is clearly before "5/18/2017 05:55 AM".

If your users are *consistently* expecting the opposite interpretation, you could pre-process the input to swap values around. However, it might be safer to fail validation and force them to enter "12:00 noon", or even reject "12:00" completely and make them enter "12:01 PM", which is (I think) unambiguous.

Answer (score 2):

> currenTime = "5/18/2017 05:55 AM"
>   timetwo = "5/18/2017  12:00 AM"
>   currentTime.isBefore(timetwo) => fails

When you say "fails" you means returns false - and this is expected. 5:55am is *not* before midnight as midnight is the *start* of the day, not the end of the day.

Comment: @EngineerDollery It is definitely *ambiguous*, and there may be some places with the opposite convention, but the "12am = midnight, 12pm = noon" interpretation is extremely widespread (e.g. on 12-hour digital clocks) and a lot more than "opinion" or "making it up".

Comment: I agree, it is ambiguous - but not in software development/libraries - and 100% not in momentjs

Comment: No, he's not making it up. It might be true that there are no standards in the English language for the use of it, but by convention it is how it is defined. 12:00 a.m. is midnight, 12:00 p.m. is midday, and I think that it is only 12:00 p.m. that is not defined since noon is neither a.m. nor p.m., while midnight can be both. a.m. is however most definitely the start of the day and not the end of it.

Comment: @JimmyStenke To be fair, Wikipedia does list some examples of the opposite usage, although I'd never come upon any myself. And both are equally ambiguous, because "noon in the afternoon" is no more logical than "noon in the morning".

Comment: 12:01 is tomorrow, why would 12:00 be yesterday? Makes sense to me. If moment.js says that's the way it handles it, I would say that's the answer, no?

Comment: I don't see an issue with the answer if it's true for moment.js. That's what the question is about.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I would be very surprised if a library implemented it the other way, but maybe that's just a cultural bias. To do so, they would have to special case "12:00AM" and "12:00:00AM" to be a special case, with different logic from "12:01AM" and "12:00:01AM" - unless there are people who expect "12:59AM" to be one minute before "1:00PM"?